# NW extension in Netlogo

Tags: node.js, gis, netlogo

I tried to run this model , but it does't start , I don't understand what is wrong with "nw" extension. I installed netlogo 5.2.1 and the "nw" extension bundled already.
Netlogo shows an error in line 48 (nw:snapshot nodes links). The error message is "Nothing named NW:SET-SNAPSHOT has beed defined" . Please help. The whole code is

```
extensions [gis nw table array]
breed [leavers leaver]
breed [followers follower]
breed [officers officer ]
breed [ nodes node ]
turtles-own [voisins]
leavers-own [ cur-link speed path-end current start to-node from-node origin destin]
globals [network walls itc itc-dataset walls-dataset officer_walkspeed leaver_walkspeed follower_walkspeed interaction_time person_size  max_preevacuation_delay loaded ticks_per_sec arr-e v path1 next-node distance100 distance200]

undirected-link-breed [  friendships friendship ]
to startup ;; called when first loaded
   read-gis-datasets
end   
to setup
  clear-all-but-globals ;; don't loose datasets
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  setup-world-envelope
  draw-world
  setup-paths-graph

 ask nodes [setxy xcor ycor 
    if show_names? = True [show-names]]

  setup-leavers

end

to clear-all-but-globals reset-ticks ct cp cd clear-links clear-all-plots clear-output end
to read-gis-datasets
  ;set walls gis:load-dataset "walls.shp"
  set network    gis:load-dataset "BRT.shp"
  ;set itc    gis:load-dataset "itc.shp"
end
to setup-world-envelope
  let world ( gis:envelope-of network ) ;; [ minimum-x maximum-x minimum-y maximum-y ]
  gis:set-world-envelope (world)
end
to setup-paths-graph
  set-default-shape nodes "circle"
  foreach polylines-of network 3 [
(foreach butlast ? butfirst ? [ if ?1 != ?2 [ ;; skip nodes on top of each other due to rounding
  let n1 new-node-at first ?1 last ?1
  let n2 new-node-at first ?2 last ?2
  ask n1 [create-link-with n2]
]])
  ]
  ask nodes [hide-turtle]
  nw:set-snapshot nodes links
end

to-report polylines-of [dataset decimalplaces]
  let polylines gis:feature-list-of dataset                              ;; start with a features list
  set polylines map [first ?] map [gis:vertex-lists-of ?] polylines      ;; convert to virtex lists
  set polylines map [map [gis:location-of ?] ?] polylines                ;; convert to netlogo float coords.
  set polylines remove [] map [remove [] ?] polylines                    ;; remove empty poly-sets .. not visible
  set polylines map [map [map [precision ? decimalplaces] ?] ?] polylines        ;; round to decimalplaces
    ;; note: probably should break polylines with empty coord pairs in the middle of the polyline
  report polylines ;; Note: polylines with a few off-world points simply skip them.
end

to-report new-node-at [x y] ; returns a node at x,y creating one if there isn't one there.
  let n nodes with [xcor = x and ycor = y]
  ifelse any? n [set n one-of n] [create-nodes 1 [setxy x y set size 2 set n self]]
  report n

end
to show-names
   ifelse label = ""
   [set label (word who " ")] 
    [set label ""]
end
to draw-world
  gis:set-drawing-color [255   0   0]    gis:draw network 1
end
to setup-leavers
  set-default-shape leavers "person"
  set leaver_walkspeed 1
  create-leavers num-leaver [

    set size 1 
    set origin one-of nodes
    if origin = 100 or origin = 200 
    [show origin
    set origin one-of nodes]


    move-to origin
   show origin
   ask origin [set distance100 nw:distance-to node 110]
   ask origin [set distance200 nw:distance-to node 210]
   ifelse distance100 > distance200
   [ask origin [set path1 nw:turtles-on-path-to node 210]]
   [ask origin [set path1 nw:turtles-on-path-to node 110]]
   ;[set destin node 200]

   ;[set destin node 100]
   let a array:from-list path1
   set destin array:item a 1 

  ]


end
to go
 tick
    ask leavers
  [ 
   if distance destin < 0.01 ;; round off error fix
        [ set origin destin 
      move-to origin

     ask origin [set distance100 nw:distance-to node 110]
   ask origin [set distance200 nw:distance-to node 210]
   ifelse distance100 > distance200
   [ask origin [set path1 nw:turtles-on-path-to node 210]]
   [ask origin [set path1 nw:turtles-on-path-to node 110]]   ;[set destin node 200]

   let a array:from-list path1
if array:length a > 1 
   [set destin array:item a 1 ]
 ;origin  array:item a 1  ;set next-node one-of [link-neighbors] of to-node  face to-node destin] ]
  ]
    face destin 
    fd 0.01
  ] 

    end
to create-shortest-path
  ask nodes [set color green]

  if Origin = Destin [user-message "Please select two different nodes" stop]
  ask node Origin [set color blue]
  ask node Destin [set color blue]
 ;ask node origin [ show nw:path-to node Destin]
  ask node origin [ show nw:turtles-on-path-to node destin ]
  output-show [ nw:distance-to node destin ] of node origin ;=> 1

end
```

Comment: `set-snapshot` is not a primitive in the networks (nw) extension. Did you mean `nw:set-context`?

Comment: `set-snapshot` is a deprecated primitive - is this an old model? That would explain it.

Comment: Jen and Arthur are both right. In this particular case, I think you could replace `nw:set-snapshot` with `nw:set-context` directly and it would work.

Comment: Thank you guys ;-)
I replaced it with "nw:set-context" and problem solved
but a new problem appeared! In line 36 , 
"gis:envelope-of network" is new error! :-(

Comment: One of you three should write the answer as an answer, so that this can marked answered ;)